# How to install emacs 25 in osx yosemite

Tags: emacs

I'm currently using emacs 24 and suffering from crashes
every now and them. Perhaps v25 has bug fixes.

Whats the best way to install emacs 25 on yosemite?

Comment: Visit:  http://emacsformacosx.com/ and then click on other versions and download the most recent version from the nightly section.  For example, the latest version as of today is:  **Emacs-2015-11-14_01-41-06-5f7a2a9-universal.dmg**

Comment: The following link explains the differences between the various Emacs versions for OSX -- **What is the difference between Aquamacs and other Mac versions of Emacs?** -- http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/271/2287

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find installing Emacs from homebrew to be the most reliable approach. Using homebrew, you can also install some of the other libs which adds functionality to emacs, such as imagemagick and useful packages such as git.

Once you have brew installed, installing emacs is as simple as

```
brew install emacs
```

There are additional command line options you can give to brew to install from the head of the current dev repo etc, so you can install the most recent development version of emacs 25.

I would not install emacs 25 if your after a stable version. Although there is about to be a freeze for the latest dev version, there is still a high likelihood it will be less stable than emacs 24.5

I've been running emacs 24.5 built from homebrew on an almost daily basis and it has been very stable. What exact version of emacs are you running and how did you install it? If you cannot get 24.5 running in a stable manner, you will likely see similar results with any version. Before jumping to the dev version, I would highly recommend trying to work out why your current version is unstable. Production emacs is typically very very stable. In fact, in over 20 years of use, I can count the number of crashes on 1 hand. I have certainly had bugs in elisp code and buggy packages, but these rarely cause emacs to actually crash